# How to Deploy Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've Created a wordpress theme. Now I want to sent it to the theme markets like themeforest. Will ziping the theme folder that i created work or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Just follow store guideline and submit it. If you're targeting `themeforest` follow the its guideline to submit the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can read their specific guidelines. You should have read this before creating the theme as there are some specific quality standards you need to adhere to. - Good luck.

Refer to: https://help.author.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000472383-WordPress-Theme-Requirements

Thanks